# Recreating ListItems into adapter

Tags: android, performance, listview, adapter

I'm trying to create a ListView with an adapter which should sort and group items using complex logic (it's complex because it has a lot of ifs, but not operations)

My question is which way is better and "by what value":

1. I can refresh all items (clear, and recreate in right order) every time when user adds or removes items, and then notify adapter. This way is the best for me to avoid mistakes because I will have only 1 place where I realize that logic.
2. Create full list after creating adapter, and change it when user will add/remove items.

So, at first glance, second is much better by performance... But I'm not sure, maybe the difference isn't so much.. List will contain maximum ~200 items I think..

Maybe somebody had a similar investigation and can help me :)

Comment: Did you try something like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() ?

Comment: I use this method, i'm renewing list and after that use notifyDatChanged(), but my question which way is better.. Maybe android reinspect all items each time i use notifyDataChanged() then it looks like first way is better, because the difference in performance will be small..